# ompr objective: minimize variance of rowsums

Tags: r, glpk, mixed-integer-programming

I am using the `ompr` package with `r`, and I cannot figure out how to change the objective function to my needs. The first model is running, but the objective is not really what I need.

```
library(ompr)
library(magrittr)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr.roi)

anz_schulen <- 50
anz_sfkz <- 10


# This model works 
model <- MIPModel() %>% 
add_variable(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen, j = 1:anz_sfkz, type = "binary") %>%
set_objective(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen, j = 1:anz_sfkz), sense="max") %>%
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen) <= 7, j = 1:anz_sfkz) %>% 
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen) >= 1, j = 1:anz_sfkz) %>% 
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j = 1:anz_sfkz) <= 10, i = 1:anz_schulen) %>% 
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j = 1:anz_sfkz) >= 1, i = 1:anz_schulen)

erg <- solve_model(model, solver=with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))
```

I need the variance of the rowsums of x minimized. Anybody who knows how to do that?

```
model <- MIPModel() %>%
add_variable(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen, j = 1:anz_sfkz, type = "binary") %>%
# I NEED SOMETHING LIKE: substitute(var(rowSums(x[i,j])) ... THIS IS NOT WORKING
set_objective(substitute(var(rowSums(x[i,j]))), sense="min") %>%
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen) <= 7, j = 1:anz_sfkz) %>% 
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:anz_schulen) >= 1, j = 1:anz_sfkz) %>% 
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j = 1:anz_sfkz) <= 10, i = 1:anz_schulen) %>% 
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j = 1:anz_sfkz) >= 1, i = 1:anz_schulen)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing the variance does not work in `ompr` as it can only deal with linear objective functions. You could try using the package `ROI` with a quadratic objective function (and use a solver that can handle quadratic objective functions).

Another option is to minimize the [absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432003/converting-absolute-value-program-into-linear-program) of the linear sum of the deviations from the mean, instead of the squared one. I believe this can all be formulated as linear (in)equalities. But I am not sure if that makes sense with your use case.